# Make ImageView be as tall as it is wide?

Tags: android

Is there a way to tell an ImageView to be as tall as it is wide? Something like:

```
<ImageView
  layout_width="fill_parent"
  layout_height="whatever width ends up being"
  />
```

Thanks

Comment: Use wrap_content, wrap_content displays accroding to original value, i.e., the original height of the image <ImageView
  layout_width="fill_parent"
  layout_height="wrap_content"
  />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've recently been trying to do something similar; to my knowledge there's no way to do this through XML. One thing you could do is set the height to 0 initially, and then upon layout, in code, check the width and set the height. Something like this:

```
final ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);
ViewTreeObserver vto = imageView.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int width = imageView.getWidth();
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, width);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
}
```

Now, not having tested this, if the rest of your layout is dependent upon the size of this view, I'm not certain what effect this code will have, and if the rest of the layout will adjust itself accordingly. Might get you started though.

Comment: This got me started, I don't have a good solution yet, tricky one. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, it's kind of a pain. It's something I've needed several times though, hopefully it gets an option eventually.

Comment: i think  this line may be wrong  LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(width, width), should  LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, width) ,or other ViewGroup

Comment: @pengwang: I believe you're correct. :) This was typed off the top of my head, I forgot to specify the LayoutParams type. Updated, thanks!